# Reseting a level in unity when exit to menu is hit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a pause screen in my game having two buttons : `resume game` and `exit to main menu`
The main menu have only 1 button wish is `play`,
when i click on `exit to main menu` the main menu level is loaded,if then i click `Play` My game level scene is not restarting but continuing everything,having all it's pre created prefabs and all its game object.

How should I fix this particular bug and restarting the game when `exit to main menu` is clicked

Exit to Menu Button :

```
void OnMouseDown() {
    PauseGame.isPause=false;
    Application.LoadLevel("MainMenu");
}
```

Play button :

```
void OnMouseDown() {
    spriteRenderer.sprite = s2;
    Application.LoadLevel("Game");
}
```

[image]

[image]

I have three Prefabs:

Turret :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class Turret : MonoBehaviour {
// Use this for initialization
double LastBallTime=0.0;
double LastTurretMovingTime=0.0;
public double spawnballTime=1.5;
public double StartTurretMovingTime=35.0;
public double BallCount=2;
public bool IsRed=false;
public GameObject BallPrefab;
public GameObject RedBallPrefab;
Vector2 v ;

void Start () {
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Time.time > LastBallTime + spawnballTime) {
        LastBallTime=Time.time;
        int rand= Random.Range(1,6);
        if(rand>=1 && rand<=4)
            Instantiate(BallPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation) ;
        else{
            Instantiate(RedBallPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation) ;

        }

    }
    if (Time.time > LastTurretMovingTime + StartTurretMovingTime) {
        LastTurretMovingTime=Time.time;
        int x = Random.Range (-2,3);
        int y = Random.Range (-3,3);
        v = new Vector3 (x, y,0);
        gameObject.transform.position=v;

    }
}
void OnBecameInvisible ()
 {
    Destroy(gameObject);
 }
}
```

BALL :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {
// Use this for initialization
public static double Killed=0;
public Text ScoreTextPrefab;
 GameObject ParentCanvas;

void Start () {
    ParentCanvas = GameObject.Find ("Canvas");
}
void OnMouseDown() {
    if (!PauseGame.isPause) {
        Text t = Instantiate (ScoreTextPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation) as Text;
        t.transform.SetParent (ParentCanvas.transform, false);
        if (gameObject.name.Contains ("RedBall")) {
                t.text = "O o P s";
                RedKilled++;
        } else {
                Killed++;       
        }
        Object.Destroy (gameObject);
    }



}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}


void OnBecameInvisible ()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
 }
}
```

TurretBall manager wish is assigned for the main camera of the game scene :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class TurretBallManager : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization

public GameObject TurretPrefab;
public double turretSpawnTime=35;
public double LastTurretTime=0;
public double MaxTurret=10;
int currentTurretCount=1;
public Text Killedtxt;
Vector2 v;

void Start () {
    v = new Vector2(0,2);
    Instantiate (TurretPrefab, v, Quaternion.identity);

}
void CreateTurret()
{
    if (Time.time > LastTurretTime + turretSpawnTime) {
        LastTurretTime=Time.time;
        currentTurretCount++;
        if(currentTurretCount>1)
            v.x=TurretPrefab.transform.position.x-currentTurretCount/2;
        if(currentTurretCount<=MaxTurret){
            Instantiate(TurretPrefab,v,Quaternion.identity);
        }

    }
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    Killedtxt.text = "Kill : " + Ball.Killed;
    CreateTurret ();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using static fields anywhere? Those are not reloaded when changing scenes.

Comment: Or you have a gameObject set DontDestroyOnLoad() and your game level create everything under that gameObject?

Comment: i have some static values yes i can reset them to 0 it's not a problem but what about the prefabs ? they are still created when i go back to the game the timer as well can't I reset them ?

Comment: and no there is no gameobject wish is `DontDestroyOnLoad()`

Comment: Let me get this straight, you don't want your level to *continue* where it left off. But you want it to *reload* your scene, which is already happening according to what you are saying. If you want it the other way around application.loadlevel() is **not** the way to go.

Comment: after some research i figure out that my static variables are not being reset ( like the score and the time variable ) , but the thing that i don't understand is why the prefabs in my scene are not resetting ex: when i load the game for the first time only one prefab is created and every 15 sec another one is created . if i click on exit to main menu than i click play again i can see that the already created prefabs are still exist

Comment: Can you provide us with the code you use to generate and store these prefabs.

Comment: Are your prefabs static? (Checkbox in the inspector menu: top right)